# react native styling: ScrollView only scroll vertically, buttons stay at screen bottom

Tags: react-native, scrollview

How can I style this react native screen? Example codes and mock can be found below.

Some specific questions:

1. How can I set React Native `ScrollView` to only scroll vertically? Images inside of it is a problem for me that it expands the width of the panel and activates horizontal scroll automatically. I can't seem to disable it.
2. The bottom button could cover the long text scrolling to end.

No 3rd-party library other than react-native preferred.

```
<View style={styles.Container}>
  <ScrollView style={styles.Panel}>
    <Text>some Header</Text>
    <Image source={require('path/to/some/image')} />
    <Text>some text</Text>
    <Text>more text</Text>
    <Text>more text</Text>
    <Text>more text</Text>
    <Text>more text</Text>
  </ScrollView>
  <View style={styles.Buttons}>
    <Button style={styles.Button} onPress={onPressNext} title="next" />
    <Button style={styles.Button} onPress={onPressPrevious} title="previous" />
    {* could add more buttons here *}
  </View>
</View>

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Container: { flex:1 },
  Panel: { 
    // scrollable but only vertically
    // content here shouldn't be covered by bottom buttons
  },
  Buttons: { 
    // have dynamic height depends on number of buttons inside
    // always stay at bottom of screen
  },
  Button: { height:80 }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1- You can disable horizontal scroll by disabling overflow, I'd recommend   setting a maxWidth for the image instead so it won't show cropped

```
<ImageContainer style={{flexWrap: 'wrap'}}/>
```

2- Divide the content of the screen into 2 views, one that expands depending on the content of its children (buttons container) while the other will fill the remaining space by using flex (scrollview)

```
<Screen>
<ScrollContentContainer style={{flex:1}} />
<ButtonsContainer />
</Screen>
```

Comment: Not entirely what I was hoping for but "setting a maxWidth" is a good fix! Thank you!